# Socket.io just not working, without any error

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I try to setup a very basic socket.io bridge between my server (listening on port 8080) and my client (served by `react-scripts` on port 3000). Nothing happens and I don't even have any error to start debugging.

This is my server :

```
const server = require('http').createServer()
const Io = require('socket.io')

const io = new Io(server, {
  path: '/live'
})

io.on('connection', () => console.log('DID CONNECT'))
server.listen(8080)
```

And this is my client :

```
import React from 'react'
import makeSocket from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = makeSocket('http://localhost:8080/live')
socket.on('connect', () => console.log('DID CONNECT'))

export default () => <h1>Demo</h1>
```

No error, no success log, nothing. What is going on ? Thanks.

Edit : If that may help, it actually seems like I get this error sometimes on browser-side (using Chromium) :

```
GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MuLOZwa net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Comment: add path to makeSocket too. ([see docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-custom-path)) its shows the path is not being set in the error. whats `new` doing there, is that in the docs?

Comment: Adding the path as an argument and not directly in the url indeed did solve the problem. Thank you.
`new` is fine, it's in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

Well the client side now is:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:8080', {
    path: '/live',
});
```

This is the code for the client side that works now in case anyone was searching. The server side code is more or less same.